# My adopted cat bites and draws blood very often

Tags: behavior, biting

I adopted what I thought was a very relaxed and chill kitty back 2 - 3 months ago. She is 5 and was found in an old bread factory. I love her and I would do anything for her but I'm lost because she just keeps biting me out of nowhere and my hands and arms have marks all over them and I'm also worried about infection sooner or later.

I play with her multiple times a day, I feed her 2 times a day at the same times everyday. We have a pretty quiet home life and I'm never away from her for long. There are no other dogs or people, just the two of us.

I really just need help, I've been told that it's just her playing or "love bites" but it doesn't *feel* like that's the case. I have also had the vet check and make sure she is healthy and she is. She doesn't hiss except for the past two days she will hiss when attacking my feet while I walk. She is super clingy and sweet when she isn't biting me, I'm really at my limit here and just need any help from people who might be able to explain this.

Thank you.

Comment: I found some old questions where people had similar problems. Please have a look at the list, there are various different answers in there that I hope will help you. If you feel like none of them answer your question, please [edit] it to clarify how your question differs from the existing ones. It will be automatically marked for review.